# Read Data from JPA the ways to do it

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I read in the documentation and i see that to read the jpa data i need to use the following code.
this is the only way to read the data from the JPA tables via sql?

```
 factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + className + " p");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to read data using JPA. The example you provided is using [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html). Additionally, you can:

1. execute a native SQL query via [`EntityManager#createNativeQuery(String nativeSql)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29):

   ```
   Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");
   ```
2. use the [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html)
3. retrieve a single entity by it's primary key using [`EntityManager#find(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29):

   ```
   MyObject myObject = entityManager.find(MyObject.class, myObectId);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!i see that the first option is like in my post,regard the third option assume that i need to provide generic code that can handle any type of class and get the data from his members can i use it,if yes example will be very helpful.

Comment: The first option uses native SQL while the example in your post is using JPQL. JPQL is very similar to SQL but is not the same thing (see the link I provided). `em.find` should only be used to find a _single_ object based on its primary key in the database. Assuming `MyObject` is an entity and `myObjectId` is its primary key, you don't need any additional code other than the one line shown in my answer.