# How to select all the data of two columns from a table using JPA query method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to add in my `Repository` interface a method for the following SQL query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME  FROM TABLE_NAME
```

This SQL query works as expected, but I want to write it as a JPA query method, I've tried in many ways but didn't get it working, Please help me.

Following which I've tried but didn't work:

```
findAllByIdName(){}
findAllByIdAndName(){}
findByIdName(){}
findByIdAndName(){}
```

Comment: Please refer this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876681/read-data-from-jpa-the-ways-to-do-it

Comment: You should use `@Query` annotation for get selected column please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a result class first:

```
package com.example;

public class ResultClass{

  private Long id;
  private String name;

  public ResultCalss(Long id, String name){
     // set
  }
}
```

and then use a custom @Query:

```
@Query("select new com.example.ResultClass(e.id, e.name) from MyEntity e")
public List<ResultClass> findIdsAndNames();
```

Comment: Does that MyEntity is same as ResultClass ?

Comment: no.. MyEntity is a class annotated with @Entity. ResultClass is a POJO

Comment: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.example.ResultClass]. Expected arguments are: int, java.lang.String

Comment: In ResultClass & POJO both are int for Id & String for name

Comment: what is the definition of constructor that you are using exacly?

Comment: I'm not using my defined constructor even on class ResultCalss

Comment: there has to be a constructor with id and name params in that particular order for this to work

Comment: Now it build successfuly but when I hit API, then it returned org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: try to add the pojo class and the repository method with @Query in post marking the section with an UPDATE. There has to be something trivial missing

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, it's works!! I've removed nativeQuery = true, & value="SQL Query which you suggest", it worked with only @Query("SQL Query which you suggest")

Answer (score 2):

I have similar implementation. Custom query required to achieve this.

e.g -

```
@Query("SELECT usr.id, usr.name FROM User usr")
public List<User> findIdsAndNames();
```

And the User class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
............
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use interface- or class-based [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

```
public interface IdAndName {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}

public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    List<IdAndName> findBy();
}
```

More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878744/5380322).